# How to update Android textviews efficiently?

Tags: android, performance, textview

I am working on an Android app which encounters performance issues.
My goal is to receive strings from an AsyncTask and display them in a TextView. The TextView is initially empty and each time the other process sends a string concatenates it to the current content of the textview. 
I currently use a StringBuilder to store the main string and each time I receive a new string, I append it to the StringBuilder and call

```
myTextView.setText(myStringBuilder.toString())
```

The problem is that the background process can send up to 100 strings per second, and my method is not efficient enough.

Redrawing the whole TextView everytime is obviously a bad idea (time complexity O(N²)), but I'm not seeing another solution...

Do you know of an alternative to TextView which could do these concatenations in O(N) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an answer with the help of havexz and Greyson here, and some code [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html).
As the strings were coming in bursts, I chose to update the UI every 100ms.
For the record, here's what my code looks like:

```
private static boolean output_upToDate = true;

/* Handles the refresh */
private Handler outputUpdater = new Handler();

/* Adjust this value for your purpose */
public static final long REFRESH_INTERVAL = 100;      // in milliseconds

/* This object is used as a lock to avoid data loss in the last refresh */
private static final Object lock = new Object();


private Runnable outputUpdaterTask = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // takes the lock
        synchronized(lock){
            if(!output_upToDate){
                // updates the outview
                outView.setText(new_text);
                // notifies that the output is up-to-date
                output_upToDate = true;
            }
        }
        outputUpdater.postDelayed(this, REFRESH_INTERVAL);
    }

 };
```

and I put this in my `onCreate()` method:

```
outputUpdater.post(outputUpdaterTask);
```

Some explanations: when my app calls its `onCreate()` method, my `outputUpdater` Handler receives **one** request to refresh. But this task (`outputUpdaterTask`) puts itself a refresh request 100ms later. The `lock` is shared with the process which send the new strings and sets output_upToDate to false.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there is a newline between the strings, you could use a ListView to append the strings and hold the strings themselves in an ArrayList or LinkedList to which you append as the AsyncTask receives the strings.

You might also consider simply invalidating the TextField less frequently; say 10 times a second. This would certainly improve responsiveness. Something like the following could work:

```
static long lastTimeUpdated = 0;
if( receivedString.size() > 0 )
{
   myStringBuilder.append( receivedString );
}
if( (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeUpdated) > 100 )
{
    myTextView.setText( myStringBuilder.getChars( 0, myStringBuilder.length() );
}
```

If the strings come in bursts -- such that you have a delay between bursts greater than, say, a second -- then reset a timer every update that will trigger this code to run again to pick up the trailing portion of the last burst.

Answer (score 1):

Try throttling the update. So instead of updating 100 times per sec as that is the rate of generation. Keep the 100 strings in string builder and then update once per sec.

Code should like:

```
StringBuilder completeStr = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder new100Str = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 0;

if(counter < 100) {
  new100Str.append(newString);
  counter++;
} else {
  counter = 0;
  completeStr.append(new100Str);
  new100Str = new StringBuilder();
  myTextView.setText(completeStr.toString());
}
```

NOTE: Code above is just for illustration so you might have to alter it as per your needs.